# element div horizontal scroll

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, mousewheel

I would like to scroll the colored div when my page scroll(or when mousewheel) arrive at a particular distance from the top.In mozilla it works but In chrome and in ie i have a bad effects when the div "spostamento" is repositioned.Can you help me to solve this problem?Thank you

[Link jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpfwm/)

**Html**

```
<div class="tutto" style="width:100%;position:relative;">
<div class="spostamento" style="position:absolute;width:100%;">
    <div style="width:100%;height:300px;background-color:#000000;">
    </div>
    <div class="enter" style="height:200px;width:100%;position:relative;overflow:hidden;">
        <div class="fascia" style="height:200px;">
            <div class="sposta" style="position:absolute;width:100%;left:0px;top:0px;height:200px;">
                <div class="first" style="position:absolute;left:0px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#0F3"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;left:300px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#069"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;left:600px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#C09"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;left:900px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#6C6"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;left:1200px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#00F"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;left:1500px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#0F3"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;left:1800px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#6C6"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;left:2100px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#069"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;left:2400px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#C09"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;left:2700px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#6C6"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;left:3000px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#00F"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;left:3300px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#6C6"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;left:3600px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#069"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;left:3900px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#C09"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute;left:4200px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#6C6"></div>
                <div class="last" style="position:absolute;left:4500px;height:200px;width:300px;background-color:#0F3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%;height:1000px;background-color:#000000;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var left=0;
        var lastScroll = 0;
        var dimensioneSpostamento=0;
        var distanzaFascia=$(".fascia").offset().top-200;
        $(".sposta > div").each(function(){
            dimensioneSpostamento +=$(this).width();
        });
        var dimensioneEffettiva=dimensioneSpostamento-$(window).width();
        $(".tutto").height(dimensioneEffettiva+300+1000);
        $(window).scroll(function (event) {
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(st>distanzaFascia&&st<dimensioneEffettiva){
                    $(".spostamento").css("top",st-distanzaFascia);
                    left +=st-lastScroll;
                    if (st > lastScroll) {
                        $(".sposta").css("left", -left);                
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".sposta").css("left", -left);
                    }
                lastScroll = st;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: thank you !i have corrected my post

Comment: On a side note, [Scrollpath](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/) is a great plugin for this type of thing

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference between Firefox and Chrome is, that Chrome scrolls 100px at once for every mouse whell tick and Firefox has a smooth scrolling enabled by default, which causes scrolling a few pixel multiple times for one mouse wheel tick.

It causes a problem in your example because you do not set `$(".spostamento").css("top")` back to its original value when `st` is lower than `distanzaFascia`. You get the same effect in Firefox as well. However it is much lighter.

Try the following. I think it should do the trick:

```
if (st <= distanzaFascia) {
    $(".spostamento").css("top", 0);
    $(".sposta").css("left", 0);
}
```

Here is your updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpfwm/1/).